# Identifying Java desktop client dependencies for web apps

Tags: java, web-applications, client-side

We have a set of web apps and want to identify if they have a Java client-side dependency i.e. if they invoke the client installed JRE.

Is there an easy way to do this? or do we have to manually scan the code for  or anything else that may have a Java client dependency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to do this.

It would be easy if all your web-apps would use a `<applet>` html tag or a `<object>` html tag, then you could simply match every html source. This you can do anyway to find some of the web-apps that use java, at least on the start page of the app.

But since it is also possible to load java applets using javascript and an automatism cannot navigate through an app like a user, there is no easy way to do this.

If you have control over the clients (e.g. company internal), you might turn off java on a few clients and let the users do the checking (e.g. they will call if something does not work). Maybe you even have key users for application tests.